# Hazelcast .Net client Fast Aggregations support

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying to find out how to use aggregations on hazelcast .net client. From documentation on 3.8 it marked as supported by .net client but there is no Aggregate method on IMap and Aggregator classes not available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fast aggregation are supported starting with version 3.8.1.
You can download it from : https://hazelcast.org/clients/net/